# How To Remove encoded symbols From GET Variable PHP

Tags: php, string, filter, get

How does one remove encoded symbols converted in the get variable.  I know I could do this with javascript and some browser side verification, but I would also like to ensure these are removed on the server side just in case.

For example in a search box, someone may type "How Old Are You?"  The Get variable converts the question mark to %25253F .  How do I remove this portion from the get query in my variable?  I want to use this get string again after it has been filtered.  Current code:

```
$searchquery = str_replace(' ', '-',$_GET['search']);
$uri = preg_replace('/[^-a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $searchquery);
$checkquery = $uri;
$queryplain = str_replace('-', ' ',$uri);
```

Comment: When `$_GET` is populated it decodes back into `?`.

Comment: No, since I removed all special characters in the $uri variable, $queryplain will display: How Old Are You 25253f

Comment: Why won't you use the PHP function [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) to decode your string again?

Comment: Because I am using the string in other portions of the code, so I want to make sure it is sanitized completely before using it in the main code.  I only want letters and numbers in the string, which ensures I can safely use this string when displaying it back to the user.  **Updated to explain better**

Comment: The point of encoding a URL is so that it can pass safely to the server. Server shouldn't know that anything has been encoded. Your problem is that something has been triple encoded, and that should be fixed on the other side of things. Also, a simple string manipulation shouldn't require four separate variables.

Comment: I am not worried about the transfer, I am more worried about using the get string in that script and displaying it back to the user. If I just freely let the code hang out there, anyone can easily write an injection script and print whatever they would like.  As for the variables, I always do that to follow that path and then clean it up later.  It is also easier to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  It was due to the post form being rewritten then being re-directed by the .htaccess file.  Changing the form from something like search.php to /search/ worked to fix the issue on the get variables which in turn allowed me to remove the special characters with the code provided above.